# How to use lessR functions without load package?

Tags: r

I have a data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = c("AA", "BB"), 
  y = c(1, 2)
)
```

and the following function:

```
lessR::PieChart(
  hole = 0,
  x = x, y = y, data = df_1,
  values_digits = 1,
  values_color = "#020202",
  values_size = 1,
  color = "black",
  lwd = 1.5,
  fill = c("orange", "steelblue"),
  main = "Percent"
  )
```

The error occurs:

> Error in if (theme != getOption("theme")) { : argument is of length zero

I can't use the `library` or a `withr` (or similar) functions, as I'm using the `golem` framework, which doesn't allow loading packages even temporarily.

Comment: You could just copy the relevant source code for lessR, probably in `pc.R` and `pc.zmain.R` and `PieChart.R` though I have not checked carefully

Comment: You need a default `theme`. Add this line somewhere before the last line in your function call: `theme = lessR::style(),`